# php/mySQL - Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE error

Tags: php

I know this is a very frequent question, but for the love of god i cannot find the error in my php code. The error that i'm getting is:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in ..\virus_scan.php on line 24
```

Hopefully some fresh eyes would bring a new perspective and help me identify the mistake.
Line 24 is the line where the $sql variable is declared:

```
      if ($dbs === False)
    {
        print "can't find $database";
    }

  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // 2) Query database for data
  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------

$sql = "select unix_timestamp(date(Date_Found)) * 1000 as day, count(Virus_Name) as nb from machine_virus_info where Virus_name!='NULL' group by unix_timestamp(date(Date_Found)) * 1000 ;" 
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die('SQL Error 1: ' . mysql_error());

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    $array[] =
        array (
            $row['day'],
            $row['nb']
            );
}
```

Comment: You are missing a `;` at the end

Comment: i knew it was something simple. thanks... :D

Comment: No prob. As long as there is no upvoted answer, you can delete the question if you want (using the "delete" link)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a semicolon after your sql declaration, i.e.

```
$sql = "..." ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing `;` after the line with `$sql`.

Also, please make sure to update your code using the MySQLi framework as you can see [here](http://php.net/mysqli)

Using the `mysql_*` functions are depreciated from PHP 5.5.0 on and will generate `E_DEPRECATED` warnings!